# unable to store base 64 image in mongodb

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, base64

I have a requirement to store base 64 image data captured using webcam js in mongodb

I tried to store the image data in mongodb but unable to do so

**Server**

schema:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ProfilesSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    otherFiles: [Object]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Profiles', ProfilesSchema);
```

express js :

```
exports.otherFiles = function(req, res) {
    console.log("b4" + req.body.key.imgDataField);
    var base64Image = new Buffer(req.body.key.imgDataField, 'binary').toString('base64');
    req.body.key.imgDataField = base64Image;
    console.log("after" + req.body.key.imgDataField);
    Profiles.update({
        "_id": req.params.id
    }, {
        $push: {
            "otherFiles": {
                imgDataField: req.body.key.imgDataField
            }
        }
    }, function(error, profiles) {

        if (error) {

        }
        return res.status(200).json(fnStruncturedData(profiles));

    });
};
```

**Client**

```
 controller:

$scope.take_snapshot = function() {
    debugger;
    Webcam.snap(function(data_uri) {
        $scope.data = data_uri;
        $scope.oData = {};
        $scope.oData.imgDataField = data_uri;
        getCandidateInterviewListService.fnSavefiles(localStorage.getItem('candidateID'), $scope.oData).then(function(response) {});
        document.getElementById('my_result').innerHTML = '<img src="' + data_uri + '"/>';
        //console.log($scope.data);
    });
    $scope.set = true;
}

 service:

    this.fnSavefiles = function(id, sData) {
        debugger;
        return ajaxServiceManager.fnQuery({
            sUrl: 'http://192.168.208.31:4000/onboardvue/profiles/otherFiles/' + id,
            sMethod: "PUT",
            oData: {
                key: sData
            }
        });
    };
```

Please help me with this 
I am using mongodb ,express js

Comment: And how does that inability express itself? Some error message? If so, add it to the question.

Comment: There is no error message more over I got 200 success message but the data is not updated in "otherFiles".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I store a base 64 image like this:

**MyController.js**

```
exports.addBook = function (req, res) {
  'use strict';

  var book = new Book({
    title    : req.body.title,
    author   : req.body.author,
    category : req.body.category,
    synopsis : req.body.synopsis,
    units    : req.body.units,
    avatar: {
      data       : base64Image('your path' + req.body.avatar + '.jpg'),
      contentType: 'image/png'
    }
  });

  function base64Image(src) {
    return fs.readFileSync(src).toString("base64");
  }

  book.save(function (err, books) {
    if (err) {
        return res.status(500).send(err.message);
    }
    res.status(200).jsonp(books);
  });
};
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks @Fernando Del Olmo. Can you suggest me a way to store base64 image data directly into mongodb rather storing the file path ?

Comment: im not storing file path i use the file path to convert into base64 and then store the result